# Loading two-dimensional board

Tags: java, arrays

i have a problem with this array:

```
1.823803 1.000000 
2.214117 1.000000 
4.356716 1.000000 
4.455463 1.000000 
3.467892 1.000000 
2.480369 1.000000 
3.273540 1.000000 
3.281274 1.000000 
0.205179 1.000000 
2.103515 1.000000 
-0.057308 1.000000 
1.794524 1.000000 
3.160924 2.000000 
2.856910 1.000000 
2.247974 2.000000 
1.953566 1.000000 
4.241937 1.000000 
1.782172 1.000000 
4.869065 1.000000 
2.090794 1.000000 
1.663878 1.000000 
3.157155 1.000000 
3.501306 1.000000 
2.066036 1.000000 
4.793069 1.000000 
2.484362 1.000000 
2.201043 2.000000 
4.189059 1.000000
```

I have to load it from a file to two single boards or one two dimensional board. I don't know how to do it. They have to divide it into 1 and 2. Anybody want to help me?

Comment: We love that you're here and please show us your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any code. This question is more to suggest how I can load it. I tried a two-dimensional board and it didn't work. A friend was doing with maps.

Comment: What exactly you have problem with? Please imagine end result and how it is built step by step. Then try to describe that process and convert it into code. Post your best code attempt and describe *specific* problem with it.

Comment: My subtle point is that we don't write your code for you. You need to make an effort and we will help. That's the point of this site.

Comment: Also please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Ok, i understood guys. Thanks, I'll try to write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're many ways to read text file in `Java`. One of them is to use `Scanner`:

```
public static double[][] readTableFromFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        scan.useLocale(Locale.US);

        List<Double> data = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scan.hasNextDouble())
            data.add(scan.nextDouble());

        double[][] table = new double[data.size() / 2][2];
        Iterator<Double> it = data.iterator();
        int row = 0;

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            table[row][0] = it.next();
            table[row++][1] = it.next();
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't answer a question like this.

Comment: Thanks! I understood what this page was about. Next time I'll add my code!

Comment: @markiewicz36 Just to clarify, this site is not about "fix-my-code" questions. It is more about "give us question which can help future programmers BUT in case of homework problems include your best attempt so we wouldn't help you cheat but learn". Without honest code attempt we would need to give you ready solution which would rob you from experience needed to create it.